# How can I echo an array in an html input text value attribute

Tags: php, html, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following scenario:

I have a PHP array which has tags on it, they can be between 4 and 7.

And I need to put that PHP Array in an input type text separated by commas on the value attribute. Any idea how can I do this?

The input text is a plugin for tags, which is http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/

Any help would be appreciated!

This is my PHP code:

```
 while($dataTagsToPut = $resultTags->fetch_assoc()){
       array_push($stringTags, $dataTagsToPut['SOLUTION_TAGS_NAME']);
 }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="solutionTags" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(??whatgoeshere); ?>" name="solutionTags">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way:

```
echo implode(',', array_map('htmlspecialchars', $stringTags));
```

`array_map` applies a function to each element and gives you the results from each call.  Then you can `implode` the array to turn it into a string.

Should also work the other way around in this case (`implode` the array, then call `htmlspecialchars` on the resulting string), since `,` isn't special in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(implode($stringTags)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implode the array. `implode(',', $stringTags)`